# SSRS filtering with parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

i have some code who gives me a piece of a string.

```
    Public Function GetTransferedGroup(columnValue As String) As String  

Dim transferedTerm As String 
Dim transferedHeader_1 As String 
Dim transferedHeader_2 As String 

Dim transferedPart As Integer 
Dim transferedValues As String 

transferedTerm = " auf " 
transferedHeader_1 = "Übertragen der Gruppe von" 
transferedHeader_2 = "Übertragen von Gruppe von" 

If InStr(1, columnValue, transferedHeader_1, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 then

      transferedPart = InStr(1, columnValue, transferedHeader_2, vbBinaryCompare)
      transferedValues = Mid(columnValue, transferedPart + Len(transferedHeader_2) + 1, Len(columnValue) - (transferedPart + Len(transferedHeader_2))) 

   else

      transferedPart = InStr(1, columnValue, transferedHeader_1, vbBinaryCompare)
      transferedValues = Mid(columnValue, transferedPart + Len(transferedHeader_1) + 1, Len(columnValue) - (transferedPart + Len(transferedHeader_1))) 

end if

return Replace(Mid(transferedValues, InStr(1, transferedValues, transferedTerm) + Len(transferedTerm), Len(transferedValues) - InStr(1, transferedValues, transferedTerm)), "'", "") 

End Function 


Display: =Code.GetTransferedGroup(Fields!Description.Value)
```

Now i have a multiple parameter with these values

How can i filter the report with the values from the parameter, it shows only an empty report?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So you have a Report, let's say showing 100  Records. Now you also have a parameter with multiple values. For Ex Parameter as Week with it's value as Mon, Tue,Wed and so on.
You want to filter your Report or show data in your report based on Parameter chosen. Is that so??

Comment: yes, you are right. But i want filter the report based on =Code.GetTransferedGroup(Fields!Description.Value)

Comment: Ok. So does your expression =Code.GetTransferedGroup(Fields!Description.Value) actually returns some value? have you tested that.
Also you will have to create a parameter wherein you will feed value to this parameter from =Code.GetTransferedGroup(Fields!Description.Value)

Comment: yes, it returns the values i want to have. It works fine. But when i try to filter on these values i get an empty report. I tried erverything you can imagine :)

Comment: Did you managed to get it work?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you tried everything possible. You might have tried multi value parameter.
I believe you need to use multi value parameter and feed data from your Expression. So that your parameter contains all the value and then on your data-set you need to add parameter so that it filters out your exact data.

Take a look at this link, It explains how to add value to parameter and also how to filter dataset based on value from parameter.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4b45648c-9419-4b9f-b9b3-6f6eb0fdadac/how-can-we-add-multi-value-query-parameter-in-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: It would be helpful if you edit your question and post some screenshot for your dataset, your parameter and how does your parameter shows when preview. Also does your dataset return some record for now without considering any filter